# Open a Flutter project in XCode on a different computer without having to install Flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have not upgraded my Mac to Big Sur so I can not deploy my flutter project to my friend's iPhone running iOS 15. I was going to use the university library computer which has the latest version of XCode. Is there a way to copy over my project files into XCode and building it with that so that I don't have to download flutter onto the library computer?

Comment: Run pod install from your personal computer. Copy the project and run it from the library computer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.